# Couroutine wont allow me to change text in unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, text, coroutine

here im trying to open an Menu as a prefab(which works perfectly fine) and then update a text element in the prefab every second with a coroutine(what doesnt work).

```
public void openChestsMenu(GameObject window) {
    GameObject chestsMenu = Instantiate (Resources.Load ("Prefabs/Interfaces/Chests Menu")) as GameObject;
    chestsMenu.transform.SetParent (GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Canvas").transform, false);
    updateChestMenu (window);

    StartCoroutine (StartTimer (window));
}

private void updateChestMenu (GameObject window) {
    System.TimeSpan timeSpan = GameManager.playerData.getTimeLeftForNewChest ();

    Text[] texts = window.GetComponentsInChildren<Text> ();

    texts[0].text = GameManager.playerData.getChests(0).ToString() + "/4";
    texts [1].text = timeSpan.Hours + " : " + timeSpan.Minutes + " : " + timeSpan.Seconds;
}   

IEnumerator StartTimer(GameObject window) {
    isChestMenuActive = true;
    System.TimeSpan timeSpan;
    Text[] timerText = window.GetComponentsInChildren<Text> ();

    while (isChestMenuActive) {
        timeSpan = GameManager.playerData.getTimeLeftForNewChest ();
        updateChestMenu (window);
        GameManager.log (timeSpan.Hours + " : " + timeSpan.Minutes + " : " + timeSpan.Seconds);
        //timerText.text = timeSpan.Hours + " : " + timeSpan.Minutes + " : " + timeSpan.Seconds;

        yield return new WaitForSeconds (1);
    }
}
```

all called functions return right values and when i open the menu the right value is loaded correctly but it is never updated. when i log the text im trying to update the correctvalue is written in the console everey second but the text in the prefab wont update.

I tried a lot of different approaches to fix this can anyone please tell me where the mistake is?

Comment: Just tried what u said and it still doesnt work. slowly im starting to think theres something wrongwith unity. doesnt matter how i try it, i cant change the text from the coroutine! it just doesnt make any sense.

Comment: okay just saw that the refferencei used was linked to thetext component in the prefab. But shouldnt it change the text element in the actual instance of the prefab too?

Comment: I made exactly what you said. I declared a public variable for the text in the script,in which the code above lies and set the refference to the text element in the prefab. It works for the prefab but the instance of it is not affected. And when i try to instanciate the prefab from the editor and set the refference to the instanciated menu the refference gets deleted automatically when i remove the menu from the hirarchy. What should i use to set the public variable?

Comment: use coroutine only to stand up a flag, and update your text with this flag in "Update"

Comment: I think there the issue in your code. is that  Your `text` and `timerText` variables are same as both are derived using window gameobject. The value might getting overwritten.